# Changing the pin label in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Currently when I load a Google Map image of a location by passing it the longitude and latitude, it displays the address.  If the address is wrong, but you are in the right spot, how do you get the pin to display an alternate address, or even a descriptor to replace the wrong label?

I have found information about how to add [labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056330/how-to-display-a-label-next-to-a-marker-for-google-maps) next to markers, but I wonder if there is a more "up-to date" or elegant method others use to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Google Map Maker](http://www.google.com/mapmaker) to submit the correct information. Previously you were able to report an error but it doesn't seem this is possible anymore.